# MethodNotAllowed: The specified method is not allowed against this resource

Tags: amazon-s3, next.js, serverless

I want to deploy my nextjs application with the serverless cli, but I want to have my resources in eu-north-1. Im new to aws, but I have tried a bunch of things, even adding a policy that gives access to everything handling s3 buckets.

```
name: test-bucket

test-bucket:
  component: '@sls-next/serverless-component@latest'
  inputs:
    bucketRegion: eu-north-1
    policy: arn:aws:iam::<id>:policy/S3FullAccess
```

Comment: Seems like "eu-north-1" is not supported yet